# pg_dump Backup failed with Flyway (in Spring Boot)

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, database-migration, flyway

I'm trying to make a backup of my Postgres database and restore it in another Postgres database instance.

The command I'm using is:

```
pg_dump myDataBase > myDataBaseBackup.bak
```

and this one for restoring:

```
psql myNewDataBase < myDataBaseBackup.bak
```

That works fine so far. The problem is when I try to restart my Spring Boot  application I get this error from Flyway.

```
 nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Error while retrieving
the list of applied migrations from metadata table "public"."schema_version"
```

My application contains under the folder `resources/db.migration/` the files `V1.0_Something.sql` - `V1.52_Something.sql`

Any suggestions would be really apreciated!

Here´s the full stacktrace

```
2017-12-28 08:36:27.339  WARN 12071 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available)
2017-12-28 08:36:27.349 ERROR 12071 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [de/ciss/aag/config/PersistenceConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Error while retrieving the list of applied migrations from metadata table "public"."schema_version"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at de.ciss.aag.AagApplication.main(AagApplication.java:17) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Error while retrieving the list of applied migrations from metadata table "public"."schema_version"
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl.findAppliedMigrations(MetaDataTableImpl.java:248) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl.allAppliedMigrations(MetaDataTableImpl.java:182) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.info.MigrationInfoServiceImpl.refresh(MigrationInfoServiceImpl.java:97) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate$2.doInTransaction(DbValidate.java:136) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate$2.doInTransaction(DbValidate.java:131) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:72) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate.validate(DbValidate.java:131) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.doValidate(Flyway.java:1102) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.access$300(Flyway.java:62) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1012) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1006) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1418) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1006) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: permission denied for relation schema_version
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2455) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2155) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:288) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:430) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:356) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:303) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:289) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:266) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeQuery(PgStatement.java:233) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:317) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl.findAppliedMigrations(MetaDataTableImpl.java:225) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

Comment: can you provide the full stacktrace please

Comment: Did you try to execute some query on restored database to check that it is up and running? If it is, then you should try to select data from "schema_version" table. This table is created by Flyway to store in it information about all applied migrations, so it can't do anything if this table is missing or broken.

Comment: Yes, the database is up and running but i cant start the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack trace says: `ERROR: permission denied for relation schema_version`, which means that the user you use to connect to database doesn't have permissions to this table.

Try to execute this query to add required permissions:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE schema_version TO your_user;
```

Keep in mind that you should execute this query as a user, that have permission to grant permissions, for example `postgres`